# Keycloak adapter pkix path building failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keycloak

I'm currently trying to connect my spring boot microservice to keycloak to validate all token coming from the front end and validate the user. To do so, I'm using the keycloak adapter for spring boot. It's the first time I'm using Keycloak as an identity provider and I'm trying to figure out how to work with it. I've been successfull so far using the simple rest API to get all the user from Keycloak and information about the realm.

Now that I want to use the adapter providedd with keycloak I encounter a certificate error (I post all the relevant log):

```
2019-08-27 09:19:58.529 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8080/data/23
2019-08-27 09:19:58.569 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'authentication-service'
2019-08-27 09:19:58.572 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2019-08-27 09:19:58.574 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2019-08-27 09:19:58.576 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
2019-08-27 09:19:58.577 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
2019-08-27 09:19:58.577 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
2019-08-27 09:19:58.577 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils   : Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
2019-08-27 09:19:58.587 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : resolveUrls
2019-08-27 09:19:58.589 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder   : Use authServerUrl: https://192.168.222.153:8444/auth/, tokenUrl: https://192.168.222.153:8444/auth/realms/GRCC/protocol/openid-connect/token, relativeUrls: NEVER
2019-08-27 09:19:58.601 TRACE 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : --> authenticate()
2019-08-27 09:19:58.603 TRACE 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : try bearer
2019-08-27 09:19:58.604 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2019-08-27 09:19:58.604 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2019-08-27 09:19:58.690 TRACE 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    :    access_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJjT3hqT1pOQWtieXhPM0diQ1BLWVNVS2lVY3JPZTRLRXFLN21qQ2JpZHA0In0.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_Dr2MgTGVtYWlyZSIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImxsZW1haXJlIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6Ikxvw69jIiwiZmFtaWx5X25hbWUiOiJMZW1haXJlIiwiZW1haWwiOiJsb2ljLmxlbWFpcmVAaXJpc2NvcnBvcmF0ZS5jb20ifQ.signature
2019-08-27 09:19:58.752 TRACE 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Going to send request to retrieve new set of realm public keys for client authentication-service
2019-08-27 09:19:59.166 ERROR 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Error when sending request to retrieve realm keys

org.keycloak.adapters.HttpClientAdapterException: IO error
    at org.keycloak.adapters.HttpAdapterUtils.sendJsonHttpRequest(HttpAdapterUtils.java:58) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.sendRequest(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:99) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator.getPublicKey(JWKPublicKeyLocator.java:63) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.getPublicKey(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:121) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:111) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:103) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:88) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:68) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticateInternal(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:203) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:50) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.doAuthenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:57) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:572) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [spring-boot-container-bundle-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:642) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:461) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:361) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) [na:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:570) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:114) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:554) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:109) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) [httpclient-4.5.9.jar:4.5.9]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.HttpAdapterUtils.sendJsonHttpRequest(HttpAdapterUtils.java:37) [keycloak-adapter-core-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:626) [na:na]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) [na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380) [na:na]
    ... 57 common frames omitted

2019-08-27 09:19:59.166 ERROR 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier      : Didn't find publicKey for kid: cOxjOZNAkbyxO3GbCPKYSUKiUcrOe4KEqK7mjCbidp4
2019-08-27 09:19:59.166 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
2019-08-27 09:19:59.169 DEBUG 14236 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer FAILED
```

I already have resolved this problem while I was using the rest API with RestEasy by simply adding the certificate in the process.

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String password = "changeit";
keystore.load(new ClassPathResource("truststore").getInputStream(), password.toCharArray());

.resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().trustStore(keystore).connectionPoolSize(1).hostnameVerification(ResteasyClientBuilder.HostnameVerificationPolicy.ANY).build())
```

After dealing with the DNS problem, everything was fine. But now, I have the exact same problem with the adapter.

After some researches, I have added the certificate to my java cacerts and even install the certificate with windows. But none of this worked. I keep having the same error.

Here is my application properties:

```
#Keycloak configuration
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://192.168.222.153:8444/auth/
keycloak.realm=GRCC
keycloak.resource=authentication-service
keycloak.verify-token-audience=true
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.credentials.secret=49632b4b-5f8d-43af-b10d-3ecea7c114cf
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username

logging.level.org.keycloak=TRACE

keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/projects/*
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[1]=/data/*
```

And my keycloak configuration:
[image: keycloak1]
[image: keycloak2]
[image: keycloak3]

I also tried to use the keycloak truststore parameter in the application properties but it doesn't work either.

Is there anything wrong with how I'm using Keycloak?

Thx in advance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figure it out!

I was using the realm certificate instead of the Keycloak global certificate.

To get the realm certificate, you need to provide the global certificate to the JVM.

Using the openssl call to get the right certificate showed me there are two different kind of certificate.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you solved it ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, there is a different certificate for each realm in keycloak. In order to acquire these certificate from the server, you have to add the global certificate into trusted ones in the jvm. I suppose it was set during Keycloak installation. I don't really know cause I didn't install it myself. But you can use openssl to retrieve the certificate of the server. I don't remember the command, but google should provide it easily.

Comment: You just resolved your problem, and with that answer most people wont be able to reproduce it.